# Probability of at least $2$ balls in random bin when distributing $K$ identical balls to $N$ distinct bins?

Tags: probability, balls-in-bins

If we distribute $k$ identical balls to $n$ distinct bins, what is the probability a randomly selected bin will contain at least 2 balls, assuming all balls have a uniform probability of being placed in any bin and $k < n$.

Since it's probability, not "number of ways to arrange," and all distributions have equal probability, first I found the total number of distributions by assuming $k$ distinct balls, $n^k$, which means there are $n^{k+1}$ bins across all distributions.

I can figure out that if there are $k < n$ balls, the number of distributions where every bin has at most $1$ ball is $k \choose n$ (we have $k$ balls and each chooses 1 distinct bin), so guaranteed ${k \choose n} n$ bins across all distributions have fewer than $2$ balls. But I'm not sure how to figure out how many of the $n$ bins contain fewer than $2$ balls in the cases where some bins have $2$ or more balls.

I could easily be going about this from the wrong angle completely though.

Comment: What's the probability that it contains fewer than $2$ balls?  That's probably easier to work out.

Comment: That's what I'm trying to do. I can do it if every bin contains fewer than 2 balls, but am not sure how to go about it if some bins contain 2 or more.

Comment: You do not have to consider every bin. Just one special one

Comment: You have two answers, which appear to disagree.  Sort it out!

Comment: I think yours is probably correct (it gives the correct answers on the examples I worked out by exhaustive listing) but am trying to think through them both.

Comment: Mine is straightfoward.  Pick a bin. The probability of a given ball in the bin is $\frac{1}{n}$, so not in bin is $\frac{n-1}{n}$, since these events are independent the probability of all not in bin is $(\frac{n-1}{n})^k$.  Similarly for a given ball in bin and all others not is $\frac{1}{n}(\frac{n-1}{n})^{k-1}$.  Since there are $k$ balls and the events for each ball in bin are disjoint, the probabilities add, getting $\frac{k}{n}(\frac{n-1}{n})^{k-1}$.

Comment: @herb Steinberg when we are saying 'a given ball' and 'k balls' are we taking care of the fact that they are identical?

Comment: @SandipanDey Yes - the terms were used for counting only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The probability no balls are in a random bin is $P_0=(\frac{n-1}{n})^k$ and the probability that exactly one ball is in the bin is $P_1=\frac{k}{n}(\frac{n-1}{n})^{k-1}$  What you want is $P_{2+}=1-P_0-P_1$.

Answer (score 0):

Total number of ways by which $k$ identical balls can be put into $N$ boxes is ${N-1+k \choose k}$, by partitioning argument.

Number of ways a particular bin will contain 0 balls = $N-2+k \choose k$, by leaving the bin out (event $A_1$)

Number of ways a particular bin will contain exactly 1 ball = $N-2+k-1 \choose k-1$, by keeping a ball into the bin and leaving the bin out (event $A_2$)

By classical definition of probability, with $P(A^c)=1-p(A)$ and the above two events being mutually exclusive, with $P(A)=P(A_1 \bigcup A_2) = P(A_1) + P(A_2)$, the required probability will be = 1 -  $\frac{{N-2+k \choose k} + {N-2+k - 1 \choose k-1}}{N-1+k \choose k}$

Comment: The equation you gave for number of ways $k$ identical balls can be put into $N$ boxes isn't useful for calculating probability, because some of those ways will have a higher probability than others. But I think I can tweak it from there to find total number of distributions (including identical ones).

Comment: But how some ways will have probability higher than the others, this part is not clear to me, can you explain?

Comment: Because there are multiple ways for certain outcomes to occur. If we assume we have $2$ balls and $2$ bins, both balls can end up in bin $1$ or bin $2$, or one ball can end up in each for $3$ possible outcomes. However, the case where one ball ends up in each can happen if the first ball goes to the first bin, and the second ball goes to the second bin, OR if the first ball goes to second bin and the second ball goes to the first bin, making it twice as likely than the other two outcomes.